# Get Undefined while reading data from a JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

Following is my code :

```
$(function() {

    var arrayCollection = ['555testing', {
        "id" : "1",
        "parent" : "555testing",
        "text" : "555 Inc.",
  "org" : "One",
    }, {
        "id" : "2",
        "parent" : "555testing",
        "text" : "Test Company",
  "org" : "Two",
    }, {
        "id" : "3",
        "parent" : "555 Inc.",
        "text" : "Test2 Company",
  "org" : "Three",
    }, {
        "id" : "4",
        "parent" : "555 Inc.",
        "text" : "Test3 Company",
  "org" : "Four",
    }, {
        "id" : "5",
        "parent" : "555 Inc.",
        "text" : "Test4 Company",
  "org" : "Five",
    }];
    //alert(arrayCollection);

    $('#jstrees').jstree({

        'core' : {

            'data' : arrayCollection
        }
    }).on("select_node.jstree", function(e, data) {

        var node_text2 = (data.node.org);
        alert(node_text2);
    });
});
```

I want to get all the values from the json object. But when tried to get the value for `org`, i get `undefined`.

For all the other attribute's is working like,
I got value in this code.

```
var node_text2 = (data.node.parent);
alert(data.node["parent"]);
```

But i don't get `org`.

Let me know, how do i get that value.

Comment: In your object you have `orgId`, not `OrgId`, so it kind of makes sense.

Comment: Hi Seb this is my typing mistake, in my code name is same in all places.

Comment: We can only help if you show us real code.

Comment: Yes I added my original JSONArray in question.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your JSON between "text" : "Test", and "orgId":"2" there should only be one comma

```
{ "id" : "155", "parent" : "MyData", "text" : "Test", , "orgId":"2"} 
//                                                    ^
```

should be

```
{ "id" : "155", "parent" : "MyData", "text" : "Test", "orgId":"2"}
//                                                   ^
```

Comment: I wouldn't call that a _"missing value"_, but a _"typo"_.

Comment: you are right, if it is meant to have the same pattern as the first object, then it is a typo

Comment: Hi Cerbrus, here I added json manually but in my code get data from JSONArray so is this not problem.

Comment: So it does not work event with correct syntax ? Can we have the JSONArray line then ?

Answer (score 1):

Check the json you have one more comma before `"orgId":"2"`

For the next time check your json there are many online tools very useful like:

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Also there are some non-printable special unicode characters,check your server side code to prevent outputting those characters:

[image]

Comment: Hi Slaiv, here I added json manually but in my code get data from JSONArray so this is not problem.

Comment: can you post your printed array?

Comment: yes I got array like this. [{"parent":"#","id":"1","text":"One","orgId":66},{"parent":"Data2","id":"2","text":"Two","orgId":64}].

Comment: it is the only parameter having integer value... not sure it helps

Comment: There are some non-printable special unicode characters, check my updated answer

Comment: during copy and paste this error may be added but I checked my original json in online tools no error in it.

Answer (score -1):

you are getting wrong json

```
[{"parent":"#","id":"1","text":"One","orgId":66},{"parent":"‌​Data2","id":"2","tex‌​t":"Two","orgId":64}‌​]
```

Better to check service or location first from where you are getting response. Also try to use any online tool like json formatter or online json editor etc.

Comment: I changed my json to [{"parent":"#","id":"1","text":"One","orgId":"66"},{"parent":"Data2","id":"2","text":"Two","orgId":"64"}] using https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ but still same error.

Comment: your json still having error try to look with http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: this is some spacing issue, but got value for other attribute like id, text etc. so no problem with json format.